# Is it possible to register a new template file?

Tags: templates, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to create a custom user dashboard on the front end using a rewrite rule to `/dashboard/` and a custom theme file `dashboard.php`. I notice that when loading in `dashboard.php`, I have to manually include `wp-blog-header.php` or the WordPress functions don't work, and that `get_page_template()` returns `page.php` instead of `dashboard.php`.

Is there a proper way to register `dashboard.php` as a custom template in the same manner that, for example, the 404 page is registered? I'd like this page to operate independently of any page in the back-end, and just utilize my custom code.

Comment: It might be easier to remove the dashbaord widgets and add in your own custom widget, making it 1 column if needed. Would this be an option?

Comment: I need it to be on the front-end of the site, I'll basically be disabling the back-end for subscribers so they never see `/wp-admin/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use a WordPress page template. At the top of  `dashboard.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Dashboard
 */
```

Now create a page called "Dashboard" and assign it the dashboard template.

This way you're not loading WordPress yourself (nearly always bad) & WordPress & all your plugins will function as normal (creating custom endpoints in WordPress that don't ultimately map to a loop/post object can hit a lot of problems as vast swathes of the frontend assume they do).

Comment: Yea, this is what I went with, but I was hoping I could do a completely custom page so as to prevent the user from breaking it (which, in my experience, almost always ends up happening with this kind of method). Was hoping there was a "proper" way to register custom template files without having to resort to a page template, but I guess it's not possible. Thanks though!